# How to work with caching and conditional rendering in a template?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, caching

I've added a custom module function to allow the `is_front` conditional to work inside of a block template. The purpose is to display the site slogan on the homepage, but not across the rest of the site. The rule works correctly, but the site's cache is causing it to render incorrectly. If I clear the cache from the front page, the slogan displays sitewide. If I clear the cache from another site page, then the slogan doesn't display on the front page.

I'm presuming it is because the block's display is being cached in some way. Is there a simple way around this other than adding a second instance of the block?

Comment: There is now a cache context for the front page, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2830442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some solutions I can think of:

**Solution 1: Use CSS (easiest)**

Make sure the slogan has some classname you can refer to. Example: `site-slogan`. Use body classes to change slogan visibility. Here's some rough CSS to get you started.

```
/* Hide slogan for all pages */
#block-site-branding .site-slogan {
  display: none;
}
/* Show slogan for front page */
body.path-frontpage #block-site-branding .site-slogan {
  display: block;
}
```

**Solution 2: Use 2 block instances (not recommended)**

- Setup one block instance, say `block-site-branding-front` for the home page and configure it to show the slogan. Make this block visible only for `<front>` page.
- Setup another block instance, say `block-site-branding-inner` for the inner pages and configure it to hide the slogan. Make this block visible for all but `<front>` page.

You can also define a custom block in a custom module, but that would be an overkill. I think the first solution should do the trick.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. However, as it's going to be a high traffic site I figured that stopping it from rendering might be helpful. Any idea if that should be a scalability consideration or if it really doesn't matter?

Comment: Naa! That's just one line showing a slogan. Shouldn't cause a bit of trouble. You can simply hide it with CSS.

Comment: Save the kilobytes, save the world

Comment: Your other option would be to prevent the block from being cached completely (has to be built on every site then, but that's a fairly optimized use case with dynamic page cache), you'd do that by setting #cache max-age = 0 somewhere in preprocess. Solution 2 will add the url.path cache contexts, which means the block would be cached differently for every URL, which is very inefficient. A more efficient approach would be to use the url.path.is_front cache context that is new in 8.3: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts

Comment: Thanks Berdir for the explanation. That is why I mentioned "not recommended" in the second solution and the CSS solution was chosen.